# Is There Any Way to Push React State Into an Import Statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, download, state

So in React, I import a certain file using a statement like so:

```
import Search from './Pages/search';
```

However, what if the file I want to import is going to be different every single time I call up a certain function? Would something like this -

```
import {this.state.fileName} from './Pages/{this.state.extension}';
```

where the state values are filled in by an outside function, work like I want it to? Say I wanted to download the file that is associated with that dynamic import. Would something like this -

```
<a href = {this.state.fileName} download> download </a>
```

allow me to download the file? Is there a better way to go about this? Curious to know.

Answer (score 0):

If the page you want to import is going to change frequently, then may be your component can accept a `fileName` prop and then you can use that prop to dynamically import that file.

Something like this may be: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-bush-xf1zg. Here, the filename changes with each `DynamicPage` call and the filename that is passed in is imported dynamically within the `DynamicPage` function.

**Didn't completely understand what you were trying to do but hope this helps

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DynamicPage fileName="File1" />
      <DynamicPage fileName="File2" />
    </div>
  );
}

function DynamicPage({ fileName }) {
  const DynamicFile = lazy(() => import(`./${fileName}`));

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={"Loading.."}>
      <DynamicFile />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

export default function File1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>File 1</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

export default function File2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>File 2</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to share state between components.
You can:

Pass it as props manually from the parent to each child

or use React ContextApi library

or use some library such as

Recoil

Redux (more complex)